# Package org.apache.axis2 does not exist

Tags: package, apache-axis

I'm trying to import packages:

```
import org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext;
import org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService;
import org.apache.axis2.engine.ServiceLifeCycle;
```

But I'm getting errors:

```
package org.apache.axis2.context does not exist
package org.apache.axis2.description does not exist
package org.apache.axis2.engine does not exist
```

I've added `%AXIS2_HOME%\bin` in my `PATH` environment variable and have also set `C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.30\webapps\axis2\WEB-INF\lib` in my `CLASSPATH`, but I still can't compile my Java file due to the same errors.

Does anyone know what are the possible reasons?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using axis2 version  1.6.2 ,  you can use below jars to solve this.

```
AXIS_HOME/lib/axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar
```

OR

If you need maven dependency

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
  <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: there are newer versions, here is the link to the latest maven declaration.  https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/maven-plugins/axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: adding maven dependency(axis2-kernel) worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As setting the CLASSPATH is not helping, there is an alternative to specify the `lib jar` files with `javac` and `java` command i.e. using `-extdirs`

Compile your code as

```
javac -extdirs D:\Software\axis2-1.6.2\lib webservices/*.java
```

and then run your code as

```
java -extdirs D:\Software\axis2-1.6.2\lib webservices/ClientMainClass
```

Here the path `D:\Software\axis2-1.6.2\lib` is of axis2 binary distribution and not of axis2 war

`ClientMainClass` has your main method that will call your remote method using generated stub.

Hope this works for you.

All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to link/reference all the jars in %AXIS2_HOME%\lib