# Creating executable jar files from java package

Tags: java

Sorry for such a newbie question.  I am trying to create an executable jar file from a java package.  So I tried (Win 7) the following to create class files:

javac *.java

I am getting errors like "package org.apache.axis.types does not exist".  Does it mean I have to install this package on my computer?  What is the easiest way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Seems like a duplicate: try the steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641636/package-org-apache-axis2-does-not-exist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve this Java Class not found exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-this-java-class-not-found-exception)

Comment: org.apache.axis is a dependency . locate where it is and use it in -cp option of javac

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Package org.apache.axis2 does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641636/package-org-apache-axis2-does-not-exist)